# Multi region API/Lambda Architecture latency issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

We are trying to deploy our API Gateway/Lambda and route it through Route53 in following regions.

```
ap-south-1
    Lambda
    API Gateway +  Certigicate for API Gateway + Custom Domain

us-east-1
    Lambda
    API Gateway +  Certigicate for API Gateway + Custom Domain
    DynamoDB
    AWS Elastic Search Service
```

Our `lambda(ap-south-1, us-east-1)` connect to `DynamoDB(us-east-1)` and `AWS Elastic search services(us-east-1)` to fetch data.

When we test the lambda in `us-east-1` it has 200ms of execution time.

But when we test the lambda in `ap-south-1` it has around 3 seconds of execution time.

The logic is same in both the lambda. The only thing is it request dynamodb/Elastic Search service in `us-east-1` from `ap-south-1`.

**We want to understand why it takes around 3 seconds when lambda is executed from `ap-south-1`, since it is inter-region request in AWS Network infrastructure only.**

Answer (score 2):

What you are observing is a typical latency issue, since data store is too far from application.

And your architechure It is not Truly Multi-region. Even if you are in 2 region, your application is unusable if aws east goes down.

You should

1. Allow replication of dynamodb tables.
2. each lambda/applicaiton should hit only regional services and no cross region call.
3. Elastic search should be replicated using dynamodb streams.
4. If lambda is using sns and sqs, they should also hookup using dynamodb streams.

It will make sure

1. You will have low latency reads.
2. No issues if there is a regional outage.

But it will have issues like

1. Cost will be higher.
2. If writes are allowed from both the regions, race conditions might be there.

Comment: you are right, but i just want to understand once my request is in AWS Network, it should not take around 3 seconds if its a cross region. from 200ms to 3 seconds is a huge difference.

Comment: cross region latencies can be monitored here https://www.cloudping.co/. and 3 second depends on how many calls you application is making. And how you are calculating performance.

Comment: its only a single call at a time currently..its not in prod right now..we are testing the scenarios here. above link shows from ap-south-1 to us-east-1 its around  185.38ms.. so in my case it should take max around 500ms.

Comment: you can try vpc peering. https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/ and see if it helps https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-direct-connect-gateway-inter-region-vpc-access/

Comment: @RaviTuvar DynamoDB's API uses HTTP over TLS over TCP.  Setting up a TCP connection requires 1 round trip.  Negotiating TLS requires 2 round trips.  The DynamoDB request/response requires 1 round trip.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said it's probably a latency issue. 
If you make multiple synchronous requests to a different region this latencies sums up.

To investigate further, you can try [AWS X-Ray](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/). Maybe it can give you some details on where latencies develop.

https://aws.amazon.com/it/xray/